# Reboot N150 router remotely

Tags: router, remote, reboot

Is there some way to reboot a Netgear N150 router remotely?

I can't see any way in the web interface for doing this (I think my old dg834 had a diagnostics page but I can't find it on this one).

```
Version numbers:

Hardware Version    WNR1000v2
Firmware Version    V1.1.2.28
GUI Language Version    V1.0.0.74
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you discovered, I don't believe there is one.

I went through your manual to the places I thought were appropriate, searched for (re)start (re)boot and reset, and looked at the index, but nothing.

ftp://downloads.netgear.com/files/WNR1000v2/Documentation/UM/WNR1000v2_UM_19NOV2009.pdf

I suspect that unless you get it through a firmware upgrade, you are out of luck. As a side note, what a glaring omission on Netgear's part. Really inexcusable.

Comment: No kidding.  I have never owned a router that didn't include that option through the web interface.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that someone would know some hidden way of doing it, it feels like something that the engineers would have built in in some way even if it's not in the obvious GUI, just to make their own job easier but at the moment at least it seems like your answer is correct, even if it didn't help much :)

Comment: @ho1 I realize that it is a bit of a bummer when the answer does not solve the problem, but really is the correct answer, and I especially appreciate those, who mark those answers. I usually try to back up such an answer with the research that I did to prove it, showing some effort to warrant it being marked. So thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

A tricky workaround:
Go to 'Backup Settings' then 'Save a Copy of Current Settings' then restore your settings from the file (netgear.cfg)
The router will restart after restore :)

Comment: Thanks, a bit excessive, but at least it's a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to enable remote administration; Choose a single IP address you will be accessing it from and then you will have full access to the router remotely. Good luck!

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however, this is not actually an answer to the question since I already know how to access it remotely but I can't find any option for rebooting it in the interface.

Comment: then there is a problem with your firmware. Try updating your firmware.

Comment: I added a screenshot for you.

Comment: ah I see you updated your question to include that you have a Netgear, not a Belkin. That would be why. seems like you won't be able to. However, people who have a Blekin N150 who come to this question will be helped by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Wireless Settings, or LAN Setup.  Don't change anything, just click APPLY.  Watch your connection.  It will (eventually) go down, and back up, and reconnect.

I know this thread is old, but thought I'd add the solution I found.  Hope it helps someone with this Netgear N150 router.

Comment: perfect, works on wndr3700 too

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

Start cmd.exe from windows.

Type the following:

telnet [RouterIP]

-> Where [RouterIP] is the IP address of your router.

Enter your username/password, if you don't know it, look up the default user/pass for your make and model (note: thsi is different from your WEP/WPA password).

Type Help to learn how to use the menu system, or type Menu to get a list of services you can change.

Navigate through the menu's until you find the Reboot/Restart option, once you select it it should work.

Let me know how it goes!